# Publishing in IIS application with .netstandard reference

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-standard

I have a web api application that has been working fine for a year. 
The project has one layer that has the DB access and other with all entities used all across.
I have added some new entities for a new project that I'm doing now, that new project is with .netCore 2.2, I have been using some data annotations on the classes and that adds .netstandard as a reference on my project.

Now when I publish my WebApi application it doesn't run in IIS. it works locally perfect but in IIS I receive this error.

> Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'

I have checked and the reference to .netstandard is there in the project.

It might be something simple, I'm new in .netcore.
Thank you,

Comment: Check that topic: https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/328
There is many flows to resolve your problem, and it depends on your project configuration.

Comment: Will check that source, thank you